# Porque no se actualizan los estilos CSS?

Tags: php, html, css, netbeans, xampp

Me pasa a veces que tengo que eliminar los `datos de navegación`, `cookies`, `caché`, y todo para que recién se actualice los estilos que modifique en el `CSS`, que están en otra carpeta como ya saben. Utilizo el `IDE NeatBeans` y servidor `Apache (XAMPP)`.

Comment: Si no me equivoco se utilizaban unos metas para no leer el caché, pero no se que es lo ideal, como estos:<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
 
<meta http-equiv="Last-Modified" content="0">
 
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, mustrevalidate">
 
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">

Comment: Aquí tienes una posible solución https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922910/force-browser-to-clear-cache

Comment: Si el problema lo tienes mientras estás trabajando en tu aplicación puedes forzar una actualización completa de la página pulsando CTRL+F5 en tu navegador. (Si usas MAC creo que el comando es: CMD + SHIFT+R).

Comment: Yo lo que hago es usar Ctrl + R, recarga  todo, si con eso no funciona... abres el inspector y en la pestaña Network, pulsas el boton CSS y recargas la página, te saldrá la lista de css que carga, click derecho, abrir en nueva pestaña a el que no te actualiza y ahi le das Ctrl+R y ya te cargará. A mi me salva a veces

Comment: chrome, firefox y safari tienen una opción en el inspector (devtools/dev menu) para des habilitar el cache (pestaña/sección netwrok/red)

Comment: Gracias excelente solución no sabia porque no me mostraba los cambios efectuados y me tocaba cambiar de navegador

Comment: A mi tambien me sucede lo mismo, y pues vine a buscar una respuesta, pero no la he encontre en linea, y pues la unica manera de hacerlo fue utilizando las etiquetas style en php o html, e ingresar el codigo de css

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si estás trabajando en el sitio web continuamente y necesitas refrescar los cambios de CSS y JS sin que se almacenen en caché hay algunas opciones.

Puedes colocar en la cabecera lo siguiente:

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
  <meta http-equiv="Last-Modified" content="0">
  <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, mustrevalidate">
  <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
</head>
```

Si tu aplicación está trabajando en php puedes utilizar también:

```
<?php
  header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
  header("Expires: Sat, 1 Jul 2000 05:00:00 GMT"); // Fecha en el pasado
?>
```

Ahora bien, este sistema te funcionará si estás constantemente editando los estilos o scripts y necesitas ver resultados al momento.

**Otra solución**

Quizás la solución más acertada es generar versiones de los estilos o js utilizando `?123`. Por ejemplo, generamos un número random en php y lo asignamos al fichero:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/mi_estilo.css?v=<?php echo(rand()); ?>" />
<script src="/js/mi_script.js?v=<?php echo(rand()); ?>"></script>
```

Comment: muy bueno, me sirvio este <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/mi_estilo.css?v=<?php echo(rand()); ?>" /> <script src="/js/mi_script.js?v=<?php echo(rand()); ?>"></script>

Answer (score 4):

Lo mejor que puedes hacer, es agregar la fecha en formato Unix, después de la ruta del archivo, así:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css?v=<?php echo time(); ?>" />
<script src="/js/functions.js?v=<?php echo time(); ?>"></script>
```

De esta forma, evitas que si se repite (casualmente) un número generado azarosamente, no cargaras una versión archiva almacenada en la caché del navegador.